# How to use refs in vue js as querySelectAll

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, refs

What I need is to change the color of links when scrolling up and down. How can I select Link 1/2/3 by using ref?

```
<nav class="header-nav">
   <ul>
     <li class="tablet-sm-hide">
       <router-link to="/">Link 1 </router-link>
     </li>
     <li class="tablet-sm-hide">
       <router-link to="/">Link 2  </router-link>
     </li>
     <li class="tablet-sm-hide">
       <router-link to="/">Link 3 </router-link>
     </li>
       </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: What have you [already tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this method

```js
this.$refs["n1"].$el.style.color = 'red'
this.$refs["n2"].$el.style.color = 'green'
this.$refs["n3"].$el.style.color = 'blue'
```

```html
<nav class="header-nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="nav">
            <router-link to="/" ref="n1">Link 1 </router-link>
        </li>
        <li class="nav">
            <router-link to="/" ref="n2">Link 2  </router-link>
        </li>
        <li class="nav">
            <router-link to="/" ref="n3">Link 3 </router-link>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Using a snippet which is not executable is kinda pointless.

Answer (score 0):

You have access to your refs by using `this.$refs`.

**example**

```js
const anchors = this.$refs["a"];

console.log(anchors);
```